# Adding BouncyCastle Provider breaks KeyStore.load()

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore

I generated a keystore with the following command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore test.ks -storetype pkcs12
```

Then I run the following test (base64 represents that keystore I created):

```
private static final String KEYSTORE_BASE64 = "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";

@Test
public void testWithoutBouncyCastle() throws Exception {
    doTest();
}

private void doTest() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    byte[] keyStoreBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(KEYSTORE_BASE64);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    keystore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(keyStoreBytes), "secret".toCharArray());

    Key key = keystore.getKey("mykey", "secret".toCharArray());
    assertThat(key, is(notNullValue()));
}
```

The test passes.

Now I do the same, but first I add BouncyCastle provider at position 2 (1-based):

```
@Test
public void testWithBouncyCastle() throws Exception {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);

    doTest();
}
```

The test fails:

```
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect

    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2059)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:238)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at PBETest.doTest(PBETest.java:43)
    at PBETest.testWithBouncyCastle(PBETest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    ... 28 more
```

### A couple of side notes on store type

Please note that the keystore is a PKCS12 store and I try to load it as a JKS. A library I have to use does the same, hence the code. Also, JDK seems to be prepared: for `getInstance("jks")` `KeyStoreDelegator` class is used which first tries to load the 'thing' it was given as a JKS store, then it falls back to PKCS12 path.

Another observation is that `getInstance("pkcs12")` works correctly in both cases (without and with BouncyCastle). The code used in this case (not `KeyStoreDelegator`) is different from the pkcs12-related path of JKS scenario, and probably because of that it runs successfully.

### Back to the subject

The problem occurs when the PKCS12-related branch tries to decrypt something using the keystore password. It does so by first converting the keystore password to a PBE key

```
private SecretKey getPBEKey(char[] var1) throws IOException {
    SecretKey var2 = null;

    try {
        PBEKeySpec var3 = new PBEKeySpec(var1);
        SecretKeyFactory var4 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBE");
        var2 = var4.generateSecret(var3);
        var3.clearPassword();
        return var2;
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        throw new IOException("getSecretKey failed: " + var5.getMessage(), var5);
    }
}
```

and then using this key (along with algorithm parameters) to decrypt:

```
SecretKey key = this.getPBEKey(var2);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(var27.toString());
cipher.init(2, key, var28);
var38 = cipher.doFinal(var38);
```

Sorry for horrible variable names, this is what IDE gives me. `var2` is a `char[]` representing keystore password, `var27.toString()` gives '1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6', `var28` contains algorithm parameters.

`doFinal()` is the call that fails.

In the 'without BC' scenario, `Cipher` instance is from SunJCE provider (and works correctly); in the 'with BC' scenario, `Cipher` instance is provided by BC and fails.

Here is the list of providers after the BouncyCastle is installed:

```
SUN
BC
SunRsaSign
SunEC
SunJSSE
SunJCE
SunJGSS
SunSASL
XMLDSig
SunPCSC
```

So BC is before SunJCE, hence it wins the contest and provides a `Cipher`.

Unfortunatly, it is nearly impossible to avoid that 'load PKCS12 as JKS' course of action; also I would like to avoid moving BouncyCastle provider to the end of the providers list as this might break some other code.

The questions are:

1. **Is this a bug in BouncyCastle?**
2. **Is there any way to work around the problem?**

Java is Oracle JDK 1.8.0_161, BouncyCastle version is 1.54 (I also tried 1.57 which seems to be the most recent version, but I get the same results).

Comment: I'm still unclear as to why you would 1) ask for a jks keystore instance and then supply a PKCS12 file, and 2) insert the bouncycastle provider at a specific position instead of just going with `Security.addProvider(new BouncycastleProvider())`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk 1) a library we use tries to detect what 'stuff' it was given as key material; to do so, it tries to parse that 'stuff' as different containers like x509 certificate, JKS keystore, PKCS keystore, etc. And it tries JKS first. It is pretty scary to change the order :) 2) Actually, wss4j adds BC at this position. They argue that this is required. The explanation can be found here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-99 below the following line: 'Well, the ordering of the JCE providers is an ongoing...'. It is also scary to change BC position after years of working this way.

Comment: ok, so the library tries jks, gets the exception, then tries PKCS12, and it works, right? And it seems like the explanation in that wss4j issue admits that their insertion of the BC provider in a specific position is a mistake.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The library also tries to detect whether keystore loading failed due to a wrong password or due to a wrong format. And this detection produces a wrong result in this particular case... it's hard to fix this detection and not break something else :) Also, the fact that BC cannot decrypt something that SunJCE can decrypt looks like a bug.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe I'm running into an equivalent issue with Wildfly (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197119/keystore-generated-by-wildfly-is-not-readable). The issue there: Wildfly loads the keystore during start-up if it exists. If not, it will create one later on, using the then present providers (and it uses all defaults). If something caused the BC provider to be loaded by that point, it will get used. On the next Wildfly start, the provider is not present, because Wildfly itself doesn't seem to load it, causing the load to fail. As above, just the other way around