# Keystore generated by Wildfly is not readable

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keystore

I'm using Wildfly 19.1 with Bouncycastle upgraded to version 1.69.

I have this configuration:

```
<security-realm name="SslRealm">
    <server-identities>
        <ssl>
            <engine enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
            <keystore provider="jks" path=".keystoreFile" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="${keystorePassword}" alias="tomcat" key-password="${keystorePassword}" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
        </ssl>
    </server-identities>
</security-realm>
```

`${keystorePassword}` is defined in the `<system-properties>`. There are no special characters in the password or anything

The SslRealm is then used in the https-listener configuration. The result is that a keystore is generated on the first https access to the server, and everything works just fine. However, when I stop the server and start it again, I'm getting:

```
2021-09-15 18:42:26,094 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.SslRealm.key-manager: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.SslRealm.key-manager: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0018: Unable to start service
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeyManagerService.loadKeyStore(FileKeyManagerService.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.AbstractKeyManagerService.createKeyManagers(AbstractKeyManagerService.java:128)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.AbstractKeyManagerService.start(AbstractKeyManagerService.java:93)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0018: Unable to start service
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:153)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeyManagerService.loadKeyStore(FileKeyManagerService.java:175)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2116)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:243)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at org.jboss.as.domain-management@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.domain.management.security.FileKeystore.load(FileKeystore.java:112)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 15 more
```

Whether I'm using jks or pkcs12 for the provider, or just leave it out, doesn't matter.
The keystore file also cannot be read by keytool from the command line: `keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect`

What am I doing wrong?

Why is the error implying that Wildfly is attempting to load the keystore as pkcs12 if the provider in standalone.xml is set to jks? Are there other places in standalone.xml where the keystore provider would need to be set?

Comment: Does it give the same error with the password directly hardcoded (eg  <keystore  keystore-password="xxxx") in the config file ?

Comment: How did you upgrade BouncyCastle and does it work with the version shipped with WildFly 19?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins, the Wildfly is provisioned using Gradle and the wildfly-provision plugin, overriding the module version. The BC module folder ends up having the three correct JARs and an updated module.xml. The original BC version 1.62 does not work due to https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/633

Comment: @TacheDeChoco, tested, but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I've debugged the loading of the keystore, and the pkcs12 error occurs in what looks like a fall-back. It first tries to load the keystore as JKS as configured. That fails, and then it attempts PKCS12, which also fails, and only the second error is printed to the log. (sun.security.utils.KeyStoreDelegator)

Comment: I've debugged FileKeyManagerService.generateFileKeyStore(). Observations: The password arrives here correctly. Regardless of the provider in standalone.xml, this method always uses KeyStore.getDefaultType(), which returns the keystore.type from the JDK's java.security file, which in my case happens to be PKCS12 (Corretto 11.0.12-7). The keystore object looks good (AFAICT), but when it's written to disk, it's already broken, i.e. it can't be read by keytool.

Comment: Turns out that the problem is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542198/adding-bouncycastle-provider-breaks-keystore-load. If the Bouncycastle provider is present, the SecretKeyFactory used in PKCS12KeyStore.getPBEKey() uses the BC provider to generate the KeyStore key from the password. On the next Wildfly start, the BC provider is not (yet) available, so the key generated from the same password then is invalid. At this point the only workaround I can see is to force the keystore to JKS, which seems to work.